# Access a public method in the active child form from a parent form

Tags: c#

With multiple childform open, how can I access a public method in a childform from a parent form. Example:

In ChildForm

```
public int x 
{
   get; 
   set;
}
public void UpdateDatabase()
{
  // Update database code using x
}
```

In ParentForm

```
ChildForm f = new ChildForm();
f.x = 1;
f.Show();

private void button1_click()
{
  var xx = this.ActiveMdiChild as ChildForm;
  xx.UpdateDatabase();
}
```

I cannot use

```
public static void UpdateDatabase();
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: With multiple childform open, how can I access a public method in a childform from a parent form?

Comment: When you cast the `ActiveMdiChild` to `ChildForm` the method `UpdateDatabase` should be accessible, because it is public one. The method does not have to be static. So what's really the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [service layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_layers_pattern). This is an additional layer between your UI and the database code. On image below you can find four layers named:

- Presentation layer → contains the UI components
- Service layer → contains logic
- Business layer → contains the classes/models you use.
- Data layer → contains connections to the database.

[image]
<sup>source image: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx)</sup>

What you could do is copy past your code to that layer and you could reuse that code so much you will.